# Convert date to json date string in python

Tags: python, json, datetime

I have a list of dates (mm-yyyy), having only the fields of months and years:

```
d = ['09-2007', '10-2007', '03-2011', '05-2011']
```

And I need to convert them into JSON date strings..like 1154476800000.. will Python's datetime or simplejson module help in this?

Comment: those aren't serialized date strings. they're simply a javascript timestamp, which is basically a unix timestamp expressed in milliseconds. e.g milliseconds since Jan 1 1970.

Comment: and no. python's module can't help unless it knows those values are dates. they're just strings. you'd need to convert into a native python date/time value FIRST, and then output as a timestamp.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
In [30]: import datetime as DT

In [31]: import time

In [32]: d = ['09-2007', '10-2007', '03-2011', '05-2011']

In [33]: [time.mktime(DT.datetime.strptime(dstr, '%m-%Y').timetuple())*1000 for dstr in d]
Out[33]: [1188619200000.0, 1191211200000.0, 1298955600000.0, 1304222400000.0]
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to convert those months to date objects, then to time values:

```
from datetime import datetime
import time

def to_jstimestamp(dt):
    dt = datetime.strptime(dt, '%m-%Y')
    return time.mktime(dt.timetuple()) * 1000

d = [to_jstimestamp(dt) for dt in d]
```

JSON does not have a standard for representing datetime values; what you are describing are JavaScript timestamps instead.

Demo:

```
>>> json.dumps([to_jstimestamp(dt) for dt in d])
'[1188601200000.0, 1191193200000.0, 1298937600000.0, 1304204400000.0]'
```